# Re-authorize persistent login (MVC client) without triggering login UI

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am trying to figure out how a server-side client (MVC / ASP.NET Core 2) can query IdentityServer4 to retrieve various claims scopes for a persistent login created in some previous session *without prompting for login* if the persistent login is invalid (user inactive, cookie expired, etc).

We're using Implicit flow with third-party auth (Google, FB, etc) but we changed the session-duration on the cookie to a more user-friendly 30 day expiration in IdentityServer's `ExternalLoginCallback`.

Accessing claims on `HttpContext.User` (we are **not** using ASP.NET Identity) works great during the session that establishes login. On some later session, navigating to a client resource with an `[Authorize]` attribute also works: if the user had logged in previously, they transparently gain access to the resource, claims are populated, etc. If not, they're prompted for login, which is ok in response to a user-initiated action.

However, we have a requirement for the client landing page to alter the content depending on whether the user is anonymous or authenticated. A simple example would be "Register" and "Log in" links for anonymous users, but "Account" and "Log out" links for authenticated users.

Hence the reason to retrieve claims and jump-start the persistent login if it's valid, but do nothing (no login prompt) if invalid: we don't want the landing page to force every anonymous user to a login screen.

Nothing special to say about our setups on either end of the pipeline. Client:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")

.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.ClientId = "example.com.webserver";
    options.ClientSecret = "examplesecret";
    options.ResponseType = "id_token";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("example.com.identity");
});
```

IdentityServer client resource definition:

```cs
new Client
{
    ClientId = "example.com.webserver",
    ClientName = "example.com",
    ClientUri = "https://localhost:5002",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    ClientSecrets = {new Secret("examplesecret".Sha256())},
    RequireConsent = false,
    AllowRememberConsent = true,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"},
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc"},
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
        "example.com.identity"
    }
}
```

The client runs an intentional login (user clicks "Log in" link) like so:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task Login()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc", 
        new AuthenticationProperties() {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("LoginCallback")
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add a second OIDC auth flow in Setup, intercept the redirect to change the `Prompt` option to `none` so that no login prompt is shown, intercept the resulting `login_required` error message, and trigger that flow in the landing page's `PageModel` `OnGet` handler (the client app uses RazorPages).

One caveat is the handler must set flags so that this is only attempted once, and so that it can detect whether the page is being hit for the first time, or as the return-trip from the login attempt. This is achieved by just dropping a value into the Razor `TempData` which is just a cookie-based bucket of name-value pairs.

#### Add to Setup.cs

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect("persistent", options =>
{
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-persistent";
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "none";
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        },

        OnMessageReceived = context => {
            if(string.Equals(context.ProtocolMessage.Error, "login_required", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    };

    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.ClientId = "example.com.webserver";
    options.ClientSecret = "examplesecret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("example.com.identity");
})
```

#### Landing page (Index.cshtml.cs)

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private bool PersistentLoginAttempted = false;
    private const string PersistentLoginFlag = "persistent_login_attempt";

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        // Always clean up an existing flag.
        bool FlagFound = false;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData[PersistentLoginFlag] as string))
        {
            FlagFound = true;
            TempData.Remove(PersistentLoginFlag);
        }

        // Try to refresh a persistent login the first time an anonymous user hits the index page in this session
        if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !PersistentLoginAttempted)
        {
            PersistentLoginAttempted = true;
            // If there was a flag, this is the return-trip from a failed persistent login attempt.
            if(!FlagFound)
            {
                // No flag was found. Create it, then begin the OIDC challenge flow.
                TempData[PersistentLoginFlag] = PersistentLoginFlag;
                return Challenge("persistent");
            }
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost forgot... the Identity Server side also needs to add that redirect URI to it's list of accepted redirect URIs for that client id.

Comment: Do you know what is the correct way to do `Challenge("persistent")` on ASP.NET 4?

Comment: Got it, it's `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge("persistent");`

Comment: Is there a way to do this in an iframe so the browser doesn't redirect to the identity server and then come back?

Comment: @ChrisO Interesting idea. I haven't tried it but off the top of my head it sounds like that could work. I'd like to hear the outcome either way, if you try it out.

Comment: @McGuireV10 thanks for your article and SO answer, I need to implement same logic on vuejs client using oidc-client.js. I'm not using MVC, do you have any comments ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ozgurozkanakdemirci Sorry, I don't use vuejs. I'd open a new question and just reference this answer (use the URL from the "share" link under my answer to directly reference the answer itself), I'm sure you'll get an answer back quickly.

Answer (score -1):

why not just make the authentication cookie permanent? Here's an other way to do it ... You can then check authentication on the server against the authentication server.

on the client AddOpenIdConnect :

```
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context => {
                        context.Properties.RedirectUri = context.Request.Path;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    OnTicketReceived = context =>
                    {
                        context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                        context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(15);
                        context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
```

Comment: The accepted answer isn't a hack, it's leveraging the way OIDC flows are supposed to work. I personally prefer to stay logged in permanently but requiring periodic re-authentication is hardly an unusual scenario. Since the question was how to re-authorize persistent login, your answer doesn't even address the OP's question.

Comment: I have readed again the question and it was not writed he whant to re-authorize. He whants the user who has a valid session/token to be authenticated on the server. The context.Properties.IsPersistent prevent the cookie to be deleted when the browser is closed. I have removed the 'hack' mention but i think my answer is pertinent.

Comment: The OP statement "retrieve various claims scopes for a persistent login created in some previous session without prompting for login if the persistent login is invalid" is exactly what the accepted answer describes. Additionally, the OP states they expire the login after 30 days, so apparently "stay logged in forever" is not a desirable use-case for the OP.