# How to stay signed in with identity server 4?

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect

Here I am trying to implement "Stay Signed in" functionality with identity server 4 so that if user does not sign out it will keep login unlimited time, but I cant. I have tried with client settings to increase token life time unlimited (a big number) but it does not work. Have you done this yet?

Is this possible by setting any combination of followings with some values?

```
AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 5, 
IdentityTokenLifetime = 5,                
AccessTokenLifetime = 5, 
AllowOfflineAccess = true,                  
AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 5, 
RefreshTokenUsage =  TokenUsage.ReUse,
RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true, 
SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 5, 
AllowRememberConsent = false
```

Is there any different way to implement this functionalities?

This is the full client config:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "uilocal",
                ClientName = "UI development",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = false,

                RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5004/index.html"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = 
               {"http://localhost:5004/index.html"},
                AllowedCorsOrigins = {"http://localhost:5004"},

                AllowedScopes =  new List<string>
                    {
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                       "api1",
                       "mvc5",
                       "jsreport"
                    };

                AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 5,
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 5,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 5,

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 5,
                RefreshTokenUsage =  TokenUsage.ReUse,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
                SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 5,
                AllowRememberConsent = false
             }
```

Here to mention I have enabled IsPersistent on login:

```
    AuthenticationProperties properties = null;
         if (loginInputModel.RememberLogin)
          {
              properties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                  IsPersistent = true
                };
          }

 HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName, properties);
```

Here to mention I am using Implicit from angular application, consume APIs by passing access token with request header.

Any help on this is appreciated in advance. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-authorize persistent login (MVC client) without triggering login UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156134/re-authorize-persistent-login-mvc-client-without-triggering-login-ui)

Comment: It's a duplicate of my "re-authorize" question because re-auth is something you have to handle yourself when the user comes back to your site (they're anonymous until you handle it).

Comment: I think problem is related to either re-authenticate or increase life time of existing token (may be identity token or access token or refresh token). I am using access token to call apis from angular oidc client, but after a expiration the token is not working in identity server.  May be User with claims are not identified after its expiration.

Comment: are you sure the IsPersistent is actually set at the right place - you are not setting the AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc - is the "idsrv" cookie actually set with a future expiration date?

Comment: @ Leon I found in some links like the code above, I am now doing in a custom way, setting 15 days token liftime and veryfying is persistent storing in database.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it is not clear how the tokens should be used.

On login request both an access token and refresh token (include the `offline_access` scope in the token request). The [refresh token](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#refresh-tokens) is available in the hybrid, authorization code and resource owner password flows.

The access token should be short-lived (e.g. five minutes, one hour), while the refresh token should be long-lived. E.g. 30 days.

Why? Because an access token is hard to revoke in case it is intercepted. It is a self-contained package, that can't be altered (an alternative can be a reference token). So for security reasons it should be short-lived. That makes it less attractive to 'hack'.

That is why the refresh token should be long-lived, you'll need it to request a new access token. Problem with this is that the refresh token should never be intercepted, as it gives unlimited access until it expires. So the client must be able to 'keep a secret'. It is however easier to revoke a refresh token. You can also 'update' the refresh token on every request for access token.

A refresh token is only used to request a new access token. You can request a new token at any time, even if the current access token isn't expired yet. But more likely you will request a new token when the access token is about to expire or did expire.

You can send the refresh token to IdentityServer, without having to bother the user to enter credentials.

And so on, until the refresh token itself expires. In that case you'll force the user to login at least every 30 days. But if you don't want that either you can choose to use sliding expiration.

Comment: @ Ruard Thanks for your elaborate answer. I have understood your explanation, problem is we are using implicit flow that does not support token refresh.

Comment: @UtpalKumarDas Check the comment here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/719#issuecomment-230145034 This looks very much alike the answer from the link of McGuireV10, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @ Ruard Thanks again, it seems there is a way by using "hidden iframe", is there any sample implemented in this way?